# Angular8 & RxJs: handling Observable in interceptor

Tags: angular-2+, rxjs

the following tutorial uses an interceptor to show/hide a loading bar:

https://www.freakyjolly.com/http-global-loader-progress-bar-using-angular-interceptors/

```
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

  removeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const i = this.requests.indexOf(req);
    if (i >= 0) {
      this.requests.splice(i, 1);
    }
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.requests.push(req);

    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const subscription = next.handle(req)
        .subscribe(
          event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              this.removeRequest(req);
              observer.next(event);
            }
          },
          err => {
            alert('error' + err);
            this.removeRequest(req);
            observer.error(err);
          },
          () => {
            this.removeRequest(req);
            observer.complete();
          });
      // remove request from queue when cancelled
      return () => {
        this.removeRequest(req);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      };
    });
  }
}
```

The idea is to call the method `removeRequest` for every type of http response, including errors etc., to make sure the loading spinner would disappear again no matter what may happens.

I have simplified this interceptor, to favor .pipe and .tap over .subscription, and would return an observable in my `removeRequest` function:

```
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private requests: HttpRequest<any>[] = [];

  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

  removeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<any> {
    const i = this.requests.indexOf(req);
    if (i >= 0) {
      this.requests.splice(i, 1);
    }
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(this.requests.length > 0);

    return of([]);
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.requests.push(req);
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);

    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(
      event => {
        return this.removeRequest(req);
      },
      err => {
        return this.removeRequest(req);
      },
      () => {
        return this.removeRequest(req);
      }));

  }


}
```

Is there any reason at all to not favor the simplified version?